# Laravel - How can I load collection data into a table?

Tags: php, laravel, html-table, eloquent

I'm storing my data with a variable called $group_months, the following is when I dd($group_months). The numbers before the arrow representative the month, and the numbers after are the time. So 10 = October

```
Collection {#187 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    "Comp Time Used" => Collection {#292 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        10 => "12:00:00"
        11 => "09:00:00"
        "01" => "12:00:00"
      ]
    }
    "Vacation Time Used" => Collection {#322 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        11 => "04:00:00"
      ]
    }
    "Sick Time" => Collection {#325 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        10 => "03:15:00"
      ]
    }
    "OT Accrued" => Collection {#316 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        10 => "12:00:00"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use this data and fill up my table that looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Month</th>
                <th scope="col">Overtime Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Compensation Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Vacation</th>
                <th scope="col">Personal Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Sick Hours</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Jan</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Feb</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Mar</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Apr</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">May</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Jun</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Jul</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Aug</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th scope="row">Sep</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Oct</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Nov</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Dec</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

I'm not sure how to do this, maybe use some sort of loop? Thanks for the help.

Edit:
Storing collection as an array now:

```
array:4 [▼
  "Comp Time Used" => array:3 [▼
    10 => "12:00:00"
    11 => "09:00:00"
    "01" => "12:00:00"
  ]
  "Vacation Time Used" => array:1 [▼
    11 => "04:00:00"
  ]
  "Sick Time" => array:1 [▼
    10 => "03:15:00"
  ]
  "OT Accrued" => array:1 [▼
    10 => "12:00:00"
  ]
]
```

Comment: does your $group_months always contain 4 values? Vacation, sick, ot, comp? If the employee doesn't have anything pertinent to that detail, does it just return an empty array or no array for that parameter at all?

Comment: Yea it will always contain those 4 values, if theirs no time entries logged to the database for lets say OT, then dumping the data won't display the array for OT.

Comment: is there any way you can store it as an array instead of collection? Perhaps using the toArray() method? Or does the rest of your code require the object be a collection?

Comment: Ok i'm storing it as an array now.

Updated op

Comment: perfect. last question. will a month ever have more than one entry? so will the array ever contain 10 => '12' AND another october value? or do you combine all the months data together before storing it in the array?

Comment: Yea, months will have multiple time entries. I plan on summing them all into one value, I just wanted to get the table display working first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started. I would combine all the times in the controller before sending it to the view. That would make it easy. Here, if the array key exists for that month, it'll print the value for that month. If it does not exist, it won't throw an error because `array_key_exists` will just return false and do nothing else.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Month</th>
                <th scope="col">Overtime Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Compensation Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Vacation</th>
                <th scope="col">Personal Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Sick Hours</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Jan</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                @if(array_key_exists(1, $group_months['Comp Time Used']))
                <td>{{$group_months['Comp Time Used'][1]</td>
                @else
                <td>No time off used</td>
                @endif
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Feb</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                @if(array_key_exists(2, $group_months['Comp Time Used']))
                <td>{{$group_months['Comp Time Used'][2]</td>
                @else
                <td>No time off used</td>
                @endif
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. if it works, give me an upvote and a "mark as correct". Always appreciated :D

Comment: I also realized i left out a closing parenthesis on my if statements, check updated code now.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can build off this!